# Rails 3 : User's coworkers in organization relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, optimization, relational-database

I have this relationship :

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
end
```

And I would like to gather a user's coworkers (i.e. who has joined the same organization).

The easy way would be to write a method like this :

```
def coworkers
  organization ? organization.users - [self] : []
end
```

But then I started thinking and felt like I can do this through a has_many relationship.

I ended doing this :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :coworkers, :through => :organization, :source => :users
end
```

which is working just fine **except** the user gets included in the coworkers.

What I'd like to know now is :

- Is defining a method like I did a good way of achieving this ?
- Is there a way to achieve this using has_many or any relationship (or anything else) without defining an actual method, and actually excluding the user ?
- Which one would be optimal regarding the query performance, caching, or any important point I'm not aware of ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@davidb : Your answer was almost right, but the id in the conditions is not the one (the user's one) evaluated when calling user.coworkers.

This is the way to go :

```
  has_many :coworkers, :through => :organization, :source => :users, :conditions => lambda { ["users.id != ?", self.id] }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add the `:conditions` option to the relation to exclude the current user. For example:

```
has_many :co_workers, :through => :organization, :source => :users, :conditions => ["user_id != ?", id]
```

This should do it for you!